# Interesting random PHP include issue

Tags: php, random, include

I have what I think is an interesting issue with a random PHP include on a portal for my company's employees/dealers. I have a random inspirational quote appear at the top of the pages and I have the pages set to refresh every 2 minutes. The code grabs a random PHP file from a "quotes" folder so I don't have to do any more coding if i want to add more quotes. It works flawlessly about 90% of the time but every now and then I get the following error:

**Warning: include(/home/content/xx/xxxxxxxxx/html/Team/includes/quotes) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Success in /home/content/49/11856349/html/Team/includes/quote.php on line 12**

**Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../includes/quotes/' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/xx/xxxxxxxxx/html/Team/includes/quote.php on line 12**

The following is the PHP code I'm using. I can't seem to see anything wrong with it (given my limited knowledge of PHP as of this writing). If it didn't work at all, it would make more sense than working just fine most of the time. The quote files are all named **quote000.php** up to **quote020.php**. I have opened all of the quote files separately in a browser and they all work error free. Incidentally, I'm using the "include" statement...not "include_once, require, etc." Thanks in advance for any advice!

```
    <?php
    $i=0;
    $myDirectory = dir("../includes/quotes");
    while($file=$myDirectory->read())
      {
        $array[$i]=$file;
        $i++;
      }
    $myDirectory->close();
    $num = count($array);
    $random = rand(0, $num);
    include "../includes/quotes/$array[$random]";
    ?>
```

Comment: Why not create a single file that returns an array with quotes and pick a random one from there?

Comment: Iterating over the directory like this will also pick up the hidden meta-directory entries (`.` and `..`). These items will be added to your array (and have a chance to be picked out), but are not `include`able. You will probably want to check that the filename ends with `.php` before adding it to the array.

Comment: Sorry John, I thought I'd looked everywhere. Can you give me the link to the question/answer, please? -- Thanks Phylogenesis...That makes sense as sometimes the error will have an address such as "../includes/quotes/.." or "../includes/quotes/." - I'll just have to figure out how to try your suggestion.

Comment: Nevermind John, just saw the link at the top of this page. Thanks!